# ifelse function for R data factoring

Tags: r, dataframe, refactoring

I have a data frame which looks like this:

| name | pos1 | pos2 | pos3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.56 | 0.2 | 0.24 |
| B | NA | 0.72 | 0.1 |
| C | NA | NA | NA |
| D | 0.1 | 0.02 | 0.1 |

The list goes on to ~500 rows.

In the prediction dataset, I want to set TRUE as **any** position having a number greater than 0.5. I dont really care if it has a NA included, I just need to know that it has AT LEAST one position that has a value >0.5.

However, I dont really need the rows that have NA for all of the positions.

The current code I have is :

```
PRED <- factor (rep(ifelse(data$pos1 > 0.500 | data$pos2 > 0.500 |
                               data$pos3 > 0.500 ,
                               TRUE, FALSE)))
```

When I tried out this code, It does the job when correctly detecting true / false but for the rows that have 1 / 2 NA's it keeps factoring it into NA (rather than T or F).

What changes do i need to make in my current code to achieve this ?
so that NA output is only obtained if ALL three positions are NAs.

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. On R 4.0.3, I get `> PRED
[1] TRUE  TRUE  <NA>  FALSE`, which is what you want, no? In fact you can check that R correctly handles `NA` in `|`: `NA | NA | TRUE` evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: Incidentally, you can just write: `PRED <- data$pos1 > 0.500 | data$pos2 > 0.500 | data$pos3 > 0.500 `. No need for `rep` or `ifelse`, and probably you don't want `factor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but you can use `case_when()` from dplyr package

```
data <- 
  data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:5],
             pos1 = c(5,0.22,NA,0,NA),
             pos2 = c(0.2,NA,1,0,NA),
             pos3 = c(NA,0.1,0.3,0.1,NA))

library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(PRED = factor(case_when(pos1 > 0.500 ~ TRUE,
                          pos2 > 0.500 ~ TRUE,
                          pos3 > 0.500 ~ TRUE,
                          is.na(pos1) & is.na(pos2) & is.na(pos3) ~ NA,
                          TRUE ~ FALSE)))
```

This will generate the factor in a new column

```
> data$PRED
[1] TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE <NA> 
Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df [2:4] %>% 
apply(1,function(x) any(x[1]>0.5,x[2]>0.5,x[3]>0.5,na.rm = T)) %>% 
cbind(df)
```

[image]